# android finish() not finishing my activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have 2 activity (Nota and Pembayaran) activity.

in Nota activity, I show some data on textview. when layout_link_pembayaran clicked, it will Intent to Pembayaran activity.

In Pembayaran activity, I show a form, when form submitted, it will intent to Nota activity.

My problem is in Nota activity still showing the old data, not the newest data based on new data that I submit in Pembayaran activity.

here the Nota activity
        package com.example.arif.celmira;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Nota extends Dashboard {
String id_pembelian;
String total_bayar;
TextView txt_tanggal_pembelian,txt_status_pembelian,txt_alamat,txt_ekspedisi;
ArrayList<String>nama_produk,gambar_produk;
ArrayList<Integer>jumlah_produk,harga_produk,subharga_produk;
ListView list_produk,list_status;
TextView txt_total_belanja,txt_total_ongkir,txt_kode_unik,txt_total_tagihan,txt_status_pembayaran;
public ArrayList<String>status,tanggal,waktu,keterangan;

String status_pembayaran;
Intent pindah;
LinearLayout layout_link_pembayaran;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nota);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nota");

    txt_tanggal_pembelian = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_tanggal_pembelian);
    txt_status_pembelian= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_status_pembelian);
    txt_alamat= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_alamat);
    txt_ekspedisi= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_ekspedisi);
    list_produk = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_produk);
    list_status = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_status_pembelian);

    layout_link_pembayaran = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_link_pembayaran);

    nama_produk = new ArrayList<String>();
    gambar_produk = new ArrayList<String>();
    jumlah_produk = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    harga_produk = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    subharga_produk = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    status = new ArrayList<String>();
    tanggal = new ArrayList<String>();
    waktu = new ArrayList<String>();
    keterangan = new ArrayList<String>();

    txt_total_belanja = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_total_belanja);
    txt_total_ongkir = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_total_ongkir);
    txt_kode_unik = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_kode_unik);
    txt_total_tagihan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_total_tagihan);
    txt_status_pembayaran = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_status_pembayaran);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    id_pembelian = i.getStringExtra("id_pembelian");

    Log.d("id_pembelian",id_pembelian);


    layout_link_pembayaran.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (status_pembayaran.equals("sudah")){
                pindah = new Intent(Nota.this,Lihatpembayaran.class);
                pindah.putExtra("id_pembelian",id_pembelian);
            }else{
                pindah = new Intent(Nota.this,Pembayaran.class);
                pindah.putExtra("id_pembelian",id_pembelian);
                pindah.putExtra("total_bayar",total_bayar);
            }
            startActivity(pindah);
            finish();


        }
    });

    RequestQueue permintaanhati = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Konfigurasi.url_nota, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONObject pm = jo.getJSONObject("pembelian");
                JSONObject pengiriman = jo.getJSONObject("pengiriman");
                JSONArray produk = jo.getJSONArray("produk");
                for (int i = 0; i <  produk.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject pp = produk.getJSONObject(i);
                    nama_produk.add(pp.getString("nama_produk"));
                    gambar_produk.add(pp.getString("gambar_produk"));
                    harga_produk.add(pp.getInt("harga_produk"));
                    jumlah_produk.add(pp.getInt("jumlah_produk"));
                    subharga_produk.add(pp.getInt("subharga_produk"));
                }
                Notaadapter na = new Notaadapter(getApplicationContext(),nama_produk,harga_produk,jumlah_produk,subharga_produk,gambar_produk);
                list_produk.setAdapter(na);

                String tgl = pm.getString("tanggal_pembelian");
                String sts = pm.getString("status_pembelian");
                total_bayar = pm.getString("total_bayar");


                Log.d("alamat",pengiriman.toString());

                String alamat = pengiriman.getString("alamat_penerima")+" "+pengiriman.getString("nama_kecamatan")+" "+pengiriman.getString("tipe_distrik")+" "+pengiriman.getString("nama_distrik")+" "+pengiriman.getString("kode_pos")+" "+pengiriman.getString("nama_provinsi");
                String ekspedisi = pengiriman.getString("nama_ekspedisi")+" "+pengiriman.getString("nama_paket")+" "+pengiriman.getString("lama_paket")+" hari";


                txt_tanggal_pembelian.setText(tgl);
                txt_status_pembelian.setText(sts);
                txt_alamat.setText(alamat);
                txt_ekspedisi.setText(ekspedisi);
                txt_total_belanja.setText("Rp "+String.format("%,d",Integer.parseInt(pm.getString("total_belanja"))));
                txt_total_ongkir.setText("Rp "+String.format("%,d",Integer.parseInt(pm.getString("total_ongkir"))));
                txt_kode_unik.setText(pm.getString("kode_unik"));
                txt_total_tagihan.setText("Rp "+String.format("%,d",Integer.parseInt(pm.getString("total_bayar"))));

                JSONArray js  = jo.getJSONArray("status");
                for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject perstatus = js.getJSONObject(i);
                    status.add(perstatus.getString("status"));
                    tanggal.add(perstatus.getString("tanggal_status"));
                    waktu.add(perstatus.getString("waktu_status"));
                    keterangan.add(perstatus.getString("keterangan_status"));
                }
                Notastatusadapter nsa = new Notastatusadapter(getApplicationContext(),status,tanggal,waktu,keterangan);
                list_status.setAdapter(nsa);

                status_pembayaran = jo.getString("pembayaran");
                if (status_pembayaran.equals("sudah")){
                    txt_status_pembayaran.setText("Sudah kirim bukti pembayaran");
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
            param.put("id_pembelian",id_pembelian);
            return param;
        }
    };
    permintaanhati.add(sr);
}

   }
```

and here my Pembayaran activity

```
    package com.example.arif.celmira;
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
    import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.UUID;

    public class Pembayaran extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//Declaring views
private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private ImageView imageView;
private EditText pemilik,bank,jumlah,tanggal,catatan;

String id_pembelian,total_bayar;



//Image request code
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

//storage permission code
private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

//Bitmap to get image from gallery
private Bitmap bitmap;

//Uri to store the image uri
private Uri filePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pembayaran);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Konfirmasi Pembayaran");

    Intent pindahan = getIntent();
    id_pembelian = pindahan.getStringExtra("id_pembelian");
    total_bayar = pindahan.getStringExtra("total_bayar");

    Log.d("pindahan",id_pembelian);

    //Requesting storage permission
    requestStoragePermission();

    //Initializing views
    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    pemilik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_rekening);
    bank = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_bank);
    jumlah = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_jumlah);
    tanggal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_tanggal);
    catatan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_catatan);

    jumlah.setText(total_bayar);

    //Setting clicklistener
    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}
/*
 * This is the method responsible for image upload
 * We need the full image path and the name for the image in this method
 * */
public void uploadMultipart() {
    //getting name for the image
    String pm = pemilik.getText().toString();
    String bk = bank.getText().toString();
    String jml = jumlah.getText().toString();
    String tgl = tanggal.getText().toString();
    String ct = catatan.getText().toString();

    //getting the actual path of the image
    String path = getPath(filePath);

    //Uploading code
    try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        //Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Konfigurasi.url_upload_pembayaran)
                .addFileToUpload(path, "bukti") //Adding file
                .addParameter("id_pembelian", id_pembelian) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .addParameter("pemilik_rekening", pm) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .addParameter("nama_bank", bk) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .addParameter("jumlah_pembayaran", jml) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .addParameter("tanggal_pembayaran", tgl) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .addParameter("catatan_pembayaran", ct) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload
        Toast.makeText(this,"Konfirmasi pembayaran sukses",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent maupindah = new Intent(Pembayaran.this,Nota.class);
        maupindah.putExtra("id_pembelian",id_pembelian);
        maupindah.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        maupindah.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        maupindah.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(maupindah);
        finish();

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
//method to show file chooser
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pilih Gambar"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
//handling the image chooser activity result
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
//method to get the file path from uri
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
//Requesting permission
private void requestStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }
    //And finally ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
//This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

        //If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if (v == buttonUpload) {
        uploadMultipart();
    }
}

   }
```

I tried using `finish()` and `pindah.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`
                `pindah.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
                `pindah.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` but no one worked.

how can Nota activity start/restart after submit form in Pembayaran activity?

**update**
I remove everything about uploading image, so in the Pembayaran activity just post Edittext, not including upload image anymore, and then **it works**, intent can finish() and when Intent going to Nota activity, the onCreate on Nota activity works (can load the new data using Volley StringRequest).

from this, I think the problem is **intent choose image on Pembayaran activity**

Comment: It is possible that `Pembayaran` is crashing which will simply return you to the `Activity` underneath it. Check your logcat for errors/exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.
Then, on your Pembayaran activity set the extras result and listen for `onActivityResult()` on Nota activity where you can set the new values.

Best regards.

Comment: I tried, on Nota activity
        `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Pembayaran.class);
        i.putExtra("id_pembelian",id_pembelian);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);`

on Pembayaran activity
        `Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("id_pembelian",id_pembelian);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();`

on Nota activity
        `@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        //some code
        }`

but still not working

Comment: Hi again. What is not working? Do your `onActivityResult` get called with no extra info or it is not called at all?

Answer (score 1):

In your Nota activity, you should use *startActivityForResult()* instead of *startActivity()* and then override the method *onActivityResult()* in the same class. From your Pembayaran activity, send your new intent using *setResult()* method so it the result would come to the callback *onActivityResult()* in Nota activity. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate()` is not call again once you go back to Nota Activity.

May be you should try to move your `StringRequest` into `onResume()/onStart()` which are called every time the activity is displayed.

Best

Comment: I tried move StringRequest to onResome()/onStart(), but still not working

Comment: try using `startActivityForResult()` but not working too

Comment: How did you implemented it ?